# Which "version" is this definition of Simplex and Simplicial Complex

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, simplex

[image]

I read this definition of simplex on an arxiv paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.10198.pdf.

I am curious which "version" of definition  of simplex are they using? It seems different from the usual definition of abstract simplicial simplex: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_simplicial_complex.

Thanks.

Comment: It is different from the usual definition.

Comment: Is it by any chance related to simplicial set; or degenerate simplex?